# Non-linear equations in R and set initial values (nleqslv)

Tags: r, nonlinear-equation

I am trying to solve two equations with 2 unknowns in R, but so far it is being a struggle.

The equations in questions are as follow:

1: *a = (52.7/x)*((1-y^T1)/(1-y))*

2: *b = (0.087/x)*((1-y^T2)/(1-y))*

Where a = 3.65, b = 8.86, T1 = -7.33, T2 = 0.14.

I have been using the nleqslv package but small changes of initial values end up being huge changes in the solution. I am not sure how to be confident on what initial values set this function to, or whether there is a better way to solve them. Any guidance will be welcome.

```
TK1 <- -13+1700/(26.90+273.15) 
TK2 <- -1.86+600/(26.90+273.15)    
Mg <- 3.65
Sr <- 8.86


fn <- function(p) {   x <- numeric(2)
     x[1] <- ((52.7/p[1])*((1-p[2]^TK1)/(1-p[2])))-Mg
     x[2] <-((0.087/p[1])*((1-p[2]^TK2)/(1-p[2])))-Sr
     x    }

pstart <-c(0.1,0.1) nleqslv(pstart, fn, jacobian=TRUE,control=list(btol=.01))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have not shown the prequel in your R code. You missed out `library(nleqslv)`.
2. `nleqslv` reports that the jacobian of your system is very ill-conditioned meaning
   that `nleqslv` can't even start the solving procedure. Suspicious and requiring further investigation.
3. I don't think your system has a solution. You can see this by dividing the first equation by the second.
   This leaves you with a single equation involving `y` only:

   a/b = (52.7/.087)*(1-y^T1)/(1-y^T2)

Assuming this single equation has a solution then substitution of `y`
into the original system leaves you with two linear equations in `x`.
If those equations are not identical then there is NO solution for `x`.
This explains the ill-conditioned jacobian.

You'll have to rethink your system of equations.